# Applying Graph Theory in shortest path calculation on a offline map

Tags: java, android, dictionary, routes, osmdroid

How do I utilize the concept of Graph Theory in finding the shortest path in an offline map in Android? I am using osmdroid library and mapnik map tiles to display a map. My problem right now is how do I drawing and calculating  the shortest path on the map basing from the user's last known location to his destination and the line should go along with the roads.

Can I utilize the geocoordinates?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GraphHopper](https://github.com/karussell/GraphHopper/) (warning: I'm the dev) in combination with [mapforge](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/) (offline renderer).

And with this [location to id](https://github.com/karussell/GraphHopper/blob/master/core/src/main/java/de/jetsli/graph/storage/Location2IDQuadtree.java) index you can query real world lat,lon coordinates and you'll get id's of the graph. With that id's you can fetch the real lat,lon via the [Graph](https://github.com/karussell/GraphHopper/blob/master/core/src/main/java/de/jetsli/graph/storage/Graph.java) interface.

Let me know if you need more info for integrating this with mapforge. For the desktop there is alreay a [rough implementation](https://github.com/karussell/GraphHopper/blob/master/core/src/main/java/de/jetsli/graph/ui/MiniGraphUI.java).